# How to enable absolute headers in Xcode C++ project

Tags: c++, xcode, header-files

I'm working on a small C++ library in Xcode and would like to normalize my file includes. As it currently stands, my `#include`s are taking the shape of `#include "Exchange.hpp"`, but would like to be able to use the `#include <Ludere/Exchange.hpp>` syntax in case I end up restructuring the project (Ludere is the project name).

I've been messing around with the build settings and have tried adding `$(SRCROOT)` to the search header paths but have yet to find a solution. We use this header syntax in Xcode at work but haven't found a way to set this up on my own project.

It might be useful to mention I'm *developing* this library, so the include directives would be used in library internal files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include header file in Xcode c++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772980/include-header-file-in-xcode-c-project) or [Xcode add header search path](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/106887) or [Adding system header search path to Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode)

Comment: @brc-dd Not really, I had already visited those pages and didn't have any luck, I appreciate it though. I've edited the post for some more information on my situation.

Comment: you certainly cannot use it like `#include <Ludere/Exchange.hpp>` unless you put your library headers into LLVM's pre-configured `include` path, instead you'll have to use `#include "Ludere/Exchange.hpp"`. Have you tried doing this and building your project? [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: I know Xcode default settings are set such that angle brackets are only used for system headers, but I thought there was a way to use them with a personal library. Regardless, I've decided it's not best practice, in terms of writing a library, to use angled bracket includes. Thanks so much for your insight!